# C# multiple switch cases same value lambda syntax

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax, switch-statement

It is possible to convert this:

```
int x = 1;
string xString;
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        xString = "1";
        break;
    case 2:
        xString = "2";
        break;
    default:
        xString = "default";
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(xString);
```

into this:

```
int x = 1;
string xString = x switch
{
    1 => "1",
    2 => "2",
    _ => "default",
};
Console.WriteLine(xString);
```

But what would be the syntax to set xString's value to the same value with multiple cases without creating a lambda line for each case?

```
int x = 1;
string xString;
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        xString = "1";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 4:
        xString = "even numbers";
        break;
    default:
        xString = "default";
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(xString);
```

Comment: You could have a single function for all numbers, such as: `xString = x.toString()`

Comment: `2 or 4` is the proposal: [#1350](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1350)

Comment: which C# Version are you using?

Comment: @MongZhu v4.0.30319

Comment: this does not look like the C# language version. Where did you check?

Comment: Sorry - here is what I found:
`Supported language versions:
default
1
2
3
4
5
6
7.0
7.1
7.2
7.3
8.0 (default)
latestmajor
preview
latest`
I previously used this line:
`Console.Write(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);`
which showed me the compiler version @MongZhu

Comment: ah ok, then you can actually use the answer by TheGeneral. You should mark it as accepted. :) happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`when` clause with switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) here as well

```cs
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        xString = "1";
        break;
    case var _ when x % 2 == 0:
        xString = "even numbers";
        break;
    default:
        xString = "default";
        break;
}
```

With C# 8 [`switch` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) and discards it may be simpler

```cs
var xString = x switch
{
    1 => "1",
    _ when x % 2 == 0 => "even numbers",
    _ => "default"
};
```

Comment: @ItamarShuval Does it answer your question? Do you need more details or information?

Comment: Yes - your response helped me. Thank you. Apologies for the late response, only saw this now

Comment: @ItamarShuval You can accept any of answers listed here, if they helped you

Answer (score 6):

You can't use ranges unfortunately, but you can use `when`.

```
str = i switch
{
    int n when (n >= 100) => "asd1",
    int n when (n < 100 && n >= 50) => "asd2",
    int n when (n < 50) => "asd3",
    _ => str
};
```

or with discards, and implicit referencing

```
str = i switch
{
   _ when i >= 100 => "asd1",
   _ when i < 100 && i >= 50 => "asd2",
   _ when i < 50 => "asd3",
   _ => str
};
```

[switch (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause)

> Starting with C# 7.0, because case statements need not be mutually
> exclusive, you can add a when clause to specify an additional
> condition that must be satisfied for the case statement to evaluate to
> true. The when clause can be any expression that returns a Boolean
> value.

Comment: C# 8 actually add ranges

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Comment: @onedevteam.com to switch statements ?

Comment: may be you should add to your answer that you need C# Version 8.0 for it to work

Comment: @onedevteam.com You [can't use ranges in switch expressions](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgpgTglgZgTwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAobAZgAI8KBhCgbxIuasuwBYKBZAChgDtgFGAEoGTFpLABDKBQAeFALzCKAZwDuMYAGMAFuOKTjLfADozlJQD4KAIgAqENcDtIJJyQH1ltuwBEIOGkAVwAbV3cjTwBfAG4PChiSGKA)